# Replacing a for-loop which iteratively runs Backward Stepwise Regressions on a list of dfs in R with an apply function to reduce compute time

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, machine-learning, feature-selection

The R scripts and a reduced version of the file folder with the multiple csv file-formatted datasets in it can all be found in my GitHub Repository found in this [Link](https://github.com/Spencermstarr/EER-Research-Project).

In my script called 'LASSO code', after loading a file folder full of N csv file-formatted datasets into R and assigning them all to a list called 'datasets', I ran the following code to fit N LASSO Regressions, one to each of the datasets:

```
set.seed(11)     # to ensure replicability
LASSO_fits <- lapply(dfs, function(i) 
               enet(x = as.matrix(select(i, starts_with("X"))), 
                    y = i$Y, lambda = 0, normalize = FALSE))
```

Now, I would like to replicate this same process for a Backward Elimination Stepwise Regression we'll keep it simple by just using the step() function from the stats library) using another apply function rather than having to use a loop. The problem is this, the only was I know how to do this is by initializing or prepping it before running it by first establishing:

```
set.seed(100)      # for reproducibility
full_fits <- vector("list", length = length(dfs))
Backward_Stepwise_fits <- vector("list", length = length(dfs))
```

And only then fitting all of the Backward_Stepwise_fits, but I cannot figure out how to put both full_fits and Backward_Stepwise_fits into the same apply function, the only way I can think of would be to use a for loop and stack them on top of each other inside of it, but that would be very computationally inefficient. And the number of datasets N I will be running both of these on is 260,000!

I wrote a for-loop that does in fact run, but it took over 12 hours to finish running on just 58,500 datasets which is unacceptably slow.
The code I used for it is the following:

```
set.seed(100)      # for reproducibility
for(i in seq_along(dfs)) {
  full_fits[[i]] <- lm(formula = Y ~ ., data = dfs[[i]])
  Backward_Stepwise_fits[[i]] <- step(object = full_fits[[i]], 
                        scope = formula(full_fits[[i]]),
                        direction = 'backward', trace = 0) }
```

I have tried the following, but get the corresponding error message in the Console:

```
> full_model_fits <- lapply(dfs, function(i)
+   lm(formula = Y ~ ., data = dfs))
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
duplicated name 'X1' in data frame using '.'
```

Comment: Write a `for`-loop and ask how to convert it into an `apply`-function. Imho this makes it easier to understand for potential answer givers.

Comment: Got it, I'll be right back with that and edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ever thought about parallelizing the whole thing?

First, you could define the code more succinctly.

```
system.time(
  res <- lapply(lst, \(X) {
    full <- lm(Y ~ ., X)
    back <- step(full, scope=formula(full), dir='back', trace=FALSE)
  })
)
#  user  system elapsed 
# 3.895   0.008   3.897 

system.time(
  res1 <- lapply(lst, \(X) step(lm(Y ~ ., X), dir='back', trace=FALSE))
)
#  user  system elapsed 
# 3.820   0.016   3.833 

stopifnot(all.equal(res, res1))
```

The results are equal, but no time difference.

Now, using `parallel::parLapply`.

```
library(parallel)

CL <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1L)

system.time(
  res2 <- parLapply(CL, lst, \(X) step(lm(Y ~ ., X), dir='back', trace=FALSE))
)
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.075   0.032   0.861 

stopCluster(CL)

stopifnot(all.equal(res, res2))
```

On this machine about 4.5 times faster.

If we now want to run a **forward step-wise selection using `res2` as `scope=`**, we need `parallel::clusterMap`, the multivariate variant of `parLapply`:

```
# CL <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1L)

res3 <- clusterMap(CL, \(X, Y) step(lm(Y ~ 1, X), scope=formula(Y), dir='forw', trace=FALSE),
                   lst, res2)

# stopCluster(CL)
```

NB: This yielded the same coefficients as using the `for` loop you showed in comments:

```
stopifnot(all.equal(lapply(FS_fits, coef), unname(lapply(res3, coef))))
```

---

**Your error** `duplicated name 'X1' in data frame using '.'` means, that in some of your datasets there are two columns named `"X1"`. Here's how to find them:

```
names(lst$dat6)[9] <- 'X1'  ## producing duplicated column X1 for demo 

sapply(lst, \(x) anyDuplicated(names(x)))
# dat1  dat2  dat3  dat4  dat5  dat6  dat7  dat8  dat9 dat10 dat11 
# 0     0     0     0     0     9     0     0     0     0     0 
# ...
```

Result shows, in dataset `dat6` the `9`th column is the (first) duplicate. All others are clean.

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 50
lst <- replicate(n, {dat <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(500*30), 500, 30))
cbind(Y=rowSums(as.matrix(dat)%*%rnorm(ncol(dat))) + rnorm(nrow(dat)), dat)}, simplify=FALSE) |> 
  setNames(paste0('dat', seq_len(n)))
```

Comment: None of the synthetic datasets I am using have any duplicate column headings, they were all randomly generated at the same time sequentially using the same custom Excel Macro by my collaborator. But, I have never gotten that particular error before, and it went away once I applied & adjusted both res and res1, so it doesn't matter what was going on there anyway! Now I am going to try the second part, the more interesting part of your answer and I'll get back to ya with what I find.

Comment: @Spencer Yeah, sometimes weird things happen here too. Sometimes, flushing workspace, restart R helps!

Comment: It appears to have reduced my runtime by at least 4 times as well, excellent!

Comment: I am about to run the parallelized version on a 1,000 dataset sub set of my 58.5k folder to evaluate the new runtime, but I have another question for you real quick. I also run a 3rd Benchmark Variable Selection method, namely, Forward Stepwise, and I figured I could very easily adjust your solution and it would work just fine.
But when I did so, every selected model only included the intercept, should I add on that question to the end of this question or ask a new question with a link to this one?

Comment: @Spencer I checked that by using `dir='for'`, if that's what you mean, both with my sample data and one of your datasets, but I can't replicate your problem. So I'm not sure what might cause your problem.

Comment: let me preface this by saying I am much more statistically and machine learning savvy than I am coding savvy at this point. But just changing the direction will not actually run a real FS Stepwise, you would need to initialize it with a null model which worked for me just fine in a for loop by setting lm(Y ~ 1), but it didn't work the same way here and caused the aforementioned error.  And you also have to assign the ceiling, where it should stop in the scope function. Like I said, this all works and runs in my for loop, how odd.

Comment: @Spencer I thought in `scope=` we define the base set from which the steps are drawn, so if you define just `Y ~ 1` there's not much there and thus just throws an intercept?

Comment: First of all friend, merry belated Christmas to ya!! 
I'll just share the syntax of the (VERY INEFFICIENT/SLOW) code I have used previously to run my FS Stepwise which always does/did run:
set.seed(11)      # for reproducibility
null_models <- vector("list", length = length(dfs))
FS_fits <- vector("list", length = length(dfs))
...

Comment: following by
set.seed(11)      # for reproducibility
for(j in seq_along(dfs)) { null_models[[j]] = lm(formula = Y ~ 1, 
                                                     data = dfs[[j]]) 
                                FS_fits[[j]] = step(object = null_models[[j]],
                                                    direction = 'forward',
                       scope = formula(full_fits[[j]]), trace = 0) }

It looks and is very clunky, and I still don't fully understand how or why, but it does run and thus, it does get the job done. Just not fact enough!

Comment: @Spencer We want `clusterMap` now, please see addendum.

Comment: I will set a reminder to try out your solution using clustermap tomorrow to see if it runs any faster, but what I actually discovered to my amazement and my dismay, is that all I had to do to get mine to return more than fits with just the intercept was to change the scope argument from scope = full_fits to, wait for it... 
scope = formula(full_fits)!